# How to create nested group in material UI React

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

```
<Autocomplete
  id="grouped-demo"
  options={options.sort((a, b) => -b.firstLetter.localeCompare(a.firstLetter))}
  groupBy={(option) => option.firstLetter}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="With categories" variant="outlined" />}
/>
```

Above example code from material UI https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#grouped

Here how can i achieve nested group

Comment: You send link to Material UI docs where is an example. What help do you need? Is it not working? What does it show?

Comment: @Sowam they want nested properties. The example from the docs is 1 level, I assume they want a group that contains other groups (more than 1 level)

Comment: @Sowam I need something group inside group and the link that I mentioned can do 1 level of grouping